# How to sum values of nested HashMap in mongo db using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-java-driver

How do I sum values of nested Java HashMap in mongo db using Java driver? Is there a way to use $objectToArray ? Or other was to sum up the values from the nested map.

this is the query in mongo db:

```
db.blogposts.aggregate(

[

{
      $addFields: {
        'total': {
            '$size': {
                '$filter':{
                    'input' : {'$objectToArray': '$upvoteUserIds'},
                    'cond' : '$$this.v'
                }
            }

        }
    }},
    { '$sort' : {'total':-1, '_id':-1}},
    { '$limit' : 2 }

  ]
```

How can I use $objectToArray with Java driver in order to sum values of a Java HashMap object in the mongo db ?

Comment: Edited. Please review and reopen